# Nodejs TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hey i am new here in nodejs and mongodb, i tyied to push comments on post in my social media project..
Here is my controller ,it shows error while pushing comments in mongodb

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

```
const Comment = require('../models/comment')
const Post = require('../models/post')

module.exports.create = function(req,res){
Post.findById(req.body.post, function(err ,post){

    if(post){
        Comment.create({
            content: req.body.content,
            post: req.body.post,
            user: req.body._id
        },function(err, comment){
            if(err){console.log("error in pushing comment")}
            post.comments.push(comment),
            post.save()
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    }
})
```

}

this is my comments schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    //comments belongs to user
    user : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    post : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Post'
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment' , commentSchema)
module.exports = Comment
```

Comment: You have a typo, check line `14` - `post.comments.,`.

Comment: .comments is not defined in post. `Console.log()` and let us knwo

Comment: @TusharShahi thank you ,you are right in post.js i write comment instead of comments

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `Promises` instead of callback functions. It will make your code way more readable. Monogoose [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) could be handy here.
As for the error, you should make a `console.log(post.comments)` to see the value for yourself.
We should see the model of `Post`. It should contain an array of `Comments`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Comment = require('./comment.model.js') // Change the path

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // comments belongs to post
    comments : {
        type: [Comment]
    },
    // Other attributes here 
},{
    timestamps: true
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post' , postSchema)
module.exports = Post
```

You'll end up with something like this:

```
const Comment = require('../models/comment')
const Post = require('../models/post')

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  Post.findById(req.body.post).then((post) => {
      if (post) {
          Comment.create({
            content: req.body.content,
              post: req.body.post,
              user: req.body._id
          }).then((comment) => {
            Post.findOneAndUpdate(
              { _id: req.body.post },
              { $push: { comments: comment } }
            ).then(() => {
              res.redirect('/')
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
          })
       }
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```